# Are the CAA and FAA Class 1 medical certificates equivalent?

Tags: faa, medical, caa-uk-regulations

Is the CAA medical class 1 certificate equivalent to the FAA class 1 medical certificate? How so?

Or does one have to convert to the FAA license in order to achieve the medical certificate?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.se it a but unclear what you are asking. FAA Medicals are not licenses they are [certificates](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/medical_certification/) issued by an [AME](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/amelocator/) that allow you to obtain a license such as a PPL (medical certs are no longer needed under the basic med rules for PPL but many have them), CPL or ATP. You will need an FAA medical certificate prior to getting a COP or ATP.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the certificates. Are the CAA medical certificates equivalent to FAA certificates?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if it's whether you can use a CAA medical in place of an FAA one to get an FAA pilot's certificate, [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43890/62) might be helpful, or maybe [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/10084/62).  Otherwise, please tell us in more detail what you mean by "equivalent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CAA medical (UK or any other country with a CAA) is not equivalent to an FAA medical, you have to get an FAA medical to get a FAA license. The classes are similar but they cannot be used in place of the other. In the UK you can get an FAA medical from several AMAs.